# Autofill a select after submission via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've got a form where users can choose a *car brand*. After that I send an SQL-query with Ajax to fill the next select with all the *models* of the selected brand.
When the form is submited I check it via PHP and if there is any error I return to the previous form with an error-message and fields filled.

The problem is that the 'model' field has the "trigger" set on brand change.
How can I fix this: call the jquery again (to show the models in the select) and display the previous model as selected?

Ajax.php

```
if ($_POST['brand_car']) {
    $sql = "SELECT id_model_car, name_model_car FROM model_car WHERE id_brand_car = :idBrand";
    $req = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $req->bindValue(':idBrand', $_POST['brand_car']);
    $req->execute();
    $model = array();
    foreach  ($req as $row){
            $model[] = array(
                            'id' => $row['id_model_car'],
                            'modele' => $row['name_model_car']                            
                        );
    }
    echo json_encode($model);
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#brand_car').change(function () { 
var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
if(id!=0)
    $.ajax({
        url: '/js/ajax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: {brand_car: id},
        success: function(data){          
            $('#model_car').html('<option id="0" value="">choose the model</option>');
            if (data.length > 0) {
                data.forEach(function (elem) {
                $('#model_car').append('<option value="' + elem.id + '" id="' + elem.id + '">' + elem.modele+ '</option>');
            });
         }}
    });
```

});

XHTML + PHP

```
<select id="brand_car" name="brand_car">
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT id_brand_car, name_brand_car FROM brand_car";
    $req = $dbh->query($sql);

    foreach  ($req as $row) {
        $val=$row['id_brand_car'];
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id_brand_car'].'" id="'.$row['id_brand_car'].'" title="'.$row['nom_brand_car'].'"';
            if($_SESSION['brand_car'] == $val ){echo ' selected';} // If return from the check_form.php
        echo ' >'.$row['nom_brand_car'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
<select id="model_car" name="model_car">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways you can fix it.

#### jQuery Approach

I think the simplest way is to refractor your `change()` and seperate the ajax call from the change event, like so:

```
$('#brand_car').change(function () { 
   var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
   getModels(id, 0);
}
function getModels(id, select) {
    if(id!=0)
        $.ajax({
           url: '/js/ajax.php',
           dataType: 'json',
           type: "POST",
           data: {brand_car: id},
           success: function(data){          
               $('#model_car').html('<option id="0" value="0">choose the model</option>');
           if (data.length > 0) {
                 data.forEach(function (elem) {
                     $('#model_car').append('<option value="' + elem.id + '" id="' + elem.id + '">' + elem.modele+ '</option>');
                 });
                 $('#model_car').val(select);
           }}
    });
}
```

This allows you to make an AJAX call by calling `getModels()`. So all you have to do is call it:

```
<select id="brand_car" name="brand_car">
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT id_brand_car, name_brand_car FROM brand_car";
    $req = $dbh->query($sql);

    foreach  ($req as $row) {
        $val=$row['id_brand_car'];
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id_brand_car'].'" id="'.$row['id_brand_car'].'" title="'.$row['nom_brand_car'].'"';
            if($_SESSION['brand_car'] == $val ){echo ' selected';} // If return from the check_form.php
                 echo ' >'.$row['nom_brand_car'].'</option>';
    }
   
?>
</select>
<select id="model_car" name="model_car">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Tag this at the end:

```
<?php
    echo '<script>getModels('.$_SESSION["brand_car"].', '.$_SESSION['model_car'].');</script>';
?>
```

This way the code is also more testable. This isn't a perfect solution and you should definitely consider using `$(function(){});` to make sure the document is ready. AJAX request also needs time to complete, so that models won't be there instantaneously when the page loads.

#### PHP Approach

Alternatively, you could consider reusing your AJAX code. Wrap it into a function:

```
function getModels($dbh, $brand_car) {
   // I know nothing about your design, but globals are no good
   $sql = "SELECT id_model_car, name_model_car FROM model_car WHERE id_brand_car = :idBrand";
   $req = $dbh->prepare($sql);
   $req->bindValue(':idBrand', $brand_car);
   $req->execute();
   $model = array();
   foreach  ($req as $row){
        $model[] = array(
                        'id' => $row['id_model_car'],
                        'modele' => $row['name_model_car']                            
                    );
   }
   return $model;
}
```

AJAX.php

```
if ($_POST['brand_car']) {
    echo json_encode(getModels($dbh, $_POST['brand_car']));
}
```

In your XHTML + PHP

```
<select id="model_car" name="model_car">
   <?php
       foreach(getModels($dbh, $_SESSION["brand_car"]) as $model) {
              echo '<option name="'.$model["id"].'" id="'.modelp["id"].'">'.$model["modele"].'</option>';
       }
   ?>
</select>
```

PS. It looks like your `$_SESSION['brand_car']` is never updated.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't add your last part (XHTML+PHP) because it worked without. Is there any way to add selected attribute to the model, after the reload of the form? for now all the models appear but none is selected, I've added the model to $_SESSION['model_car']  but I guess that the modification have to be in in the JS part.

Comment: It doesn't work,  I Tried this on the XHTML/PHP page `$("#model_car").val(<?php echo $_SESSION['model_car']; ?>);` and  `$('#model_car[value=<?php echo $_SESSION['model_car']; ?>]').attr('selected','selected');` when I see the source page I see the good value `$("#model_car").val(137);` but no effect

Comment: This should to the job ;)